# Finding an eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

I got the following statement to prove:
Let $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ be a (column-)stochastic matrix, i.e. $A \geq 0$ (which means $a_{ij} \geq 0$ $\forall i, j \in \{1, \dots ,n\}$) and 
$\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} = 1$ $\forall j \in \{1, \dots ,n\}$. Then there is a vector $x \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$ such that $x \geq 0$ (which means $x_i \geq 0$ $\forall i, \in \{1, \dots ,n\}$) and $Ax = x$.

I'm this far already. For the adjoint $A^*$ of $A$ and $y = (1, \dots, 1) \in \mathbb R^n$ we have $A^*y = y$. So $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A^*$ and it follows that $1$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$, since $\lambda \in \sigma(A) \Leftrightarrow \overline{\lambda} \in \sigma(A^*)$. 
Hence there exists a $x \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$ with $Ax = x$.

The only problem I got is to show that $x \geq 0$. So I would be thankful for helpful advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map $f$ defined by $x \mapsto \frac{Ax}{\sum_i (Ax)_i}$ defined on the (topological) disk $D$ that consists of vectors $x$ satifying
 $x_1 \ge 0, x_2 \ge 0, \ldots, x_n \ge 0, x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n = 0$ (i.e., $D$ is the standard simplex in the positive octant).

Then
$$
f : D \to D
$$
is a continuous map of a closed disk to itself (this requires a sentence or two of proof...how do we know all entries of $Ax$ are positive? How do we know they're not all zero so that the division makes sense?), and hence has a fixed point, by the Brouwer theorem. This fixed point is a positive eigenvector for $A$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this seems a bit too complicated. And I dont have the theoretical toolbox to solve it like that. Are you sure there isn't a more elementary way of seeing that $x \geq 0$?

Comment: I'm not sure that there's no more elementary way. But I am sure of this proof, which is the one I learned about 35 years ago when the same question came up, which makes me think it's probably one of the cleanest.  BTW, there's no guarantee that $x \ge 0$ for any eigenvector for the evalue $1$; if $A$ is the identity, for instance, every vector is an evec. So you're not going to get a direct proof that the one you found by your adjoint argument is of any actual use.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. Just made me curious, because i heard neither anything about the Brouwer theorem nor any standard simplecies in the corresponding lecture (or even my entire studies). So i suppose, that there should be an more obvious way. If I learn about an easier way i will definitely post it here.

Comment: If you think about the map I defined, you can apply it repeatedly. It always sends stuff in the first octant to the first octant, Since all evalues are at most 1 in magnitude, if things aren't too weird (e.g., you don't have the identity), then repeatedly applying $A$ should lead you to an evec for the maximal evalue (in the limit). But this limit will be in the first octant, if you start in the first octant, by the argument given. You can probably turn this into some kind of proof, but it won't be as simple. :)

Comment: I found an alternative argument myself, I will edit the post in the next days wehen I got the time for it! You can show with a contradiction that all entries of x have the same sign. Then you just need to multiply with 1 or -1 depending in the sign of the entries.

Comment: That sounds off-base to me, for if $A = I_2$, then $(-1, 1)$ is an eigenvector. Does your argument put any conditions on $A$?

Comment: That's strange then... Because I think my proof works. I will write it down at the weekend. Maybe you can check then if I made a mistake anywhere.